# Can I have Spyder sometimes not use anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I've been using Anaconda for a while and I installed the Spyder IDE when I first installed it.

Now, I've got to work on a project where I can't use Anaconda but I'd still like to use Spyder. Unfortunately, I can't uninstall Anaconda because some other projects require it.

Is there a way to use Spyder for both?

Note: I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: if you are using ubuntu then you can install spyder alone as `sudo apt-get install spyder3` and set the python environment

Comment: Thanks @sahasrara62. Unfortunately, I'm on Windows 7 (will edit in order to reflect that).

Comment: No project "requires Anaconda"... They might require something you installed into your interpreter, but you can always change interpreters and reinstall anything